# RxJava Observables not Parallel

Tags: rx-java2

I am new to RxJava.

I am executing a basic code :

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        abcd().map(cnt -> cnt).subscribe((s) -> System.out.println(s));

        abcd().map(cnt -> cnt).subscribe(s -> System.out.println(s));

        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long diff = endTime - startTime;
        System.out.println(diff);

    }

    public static Observable<Integer> abcd() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println();
        }
        Observable<Integer> r = Observable.fromArray(10);
        return r;
    }
}
```

Basically created two Observables & both taking 1 second in processing.
And the total time to run this code is more than 2 seconds, meaning two Observables are not executing in Parallel.

How do I change my code so as the total time of execution is 1 sec meaning two of my observable should execute in parrallel. Please post the answer wrt to RxJava.

Answer (score 0):

You are sleeping before the `Observable`s are even created so it's not exactly the same as `Observable` doing processing before it emits the result.

You can defer the execution of the `abcd()` method onto a background thread and wait for both to sub-flows to terminate:

```
Observable.merge(
    Observable.defer(() -> abcd())
       .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
       .map(cnt -> cnt)
       .doOnNext(System.out::println),
    Observable.defer(() -> abcd())
       .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
       .map(cnt -> cnt + 1)
       .doOnNext(System.out::println)
)
.blockingSubscribe(ignored -> { }, Throwable::printStackTrace);
```